# Mail messages showing up as empty

Tags: macos, mail.app

Every so often in Mail, new messages will show up as empty: "This message has no content". In fact they're not empty, but it seems their processing was interrupted... and I can't figure out how to get Mail to take another look.

So, the question: Is there any way to refresh such messages without quitting and restarting Mail? That seems to work, but it is a pain when I'm in the middle of a lot of stuff.

I'm on Mountain Lion, with Mail 6.6 and an IMAP server.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30082/why-are-some-mail-messages-shown-as-empty-with-this-message-has-no-content?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the tip, indeed that looks like the same problem! I'll try the trick in the accepted answer next time it happens: Delete and undelete the truncated message.